# Tiddlywiki: Configure '$:/config/FileSystemPaths' to save to a folder based on a field

Tags: tiddlywiki5

I have a TiddlyWiki where the tiddlers have a field "saveto". I want to add a line to the file  '$:/config/FileSystemPaths' to prefix the name of the tiddler with the value of the "saveto" field. For example, the tiddler

```
created: 20200114160408003
modified: 20200114160440095
saveto: test
tags: 
title: New Tiddler
type: text/vnd.tiddlywiki
```

should be saved at test/New Tiddler.tid

Is it possible? I don't know much about filters, these are some things I have tried:

```
 [has[saveto]addprefix[get[saveto]]] 
 [has[saveto]addprefix:get[saveto]] 
 [has[saveto]addprefix{!!saveto}]
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that works:

```
[has[saveto]get[saveto]] [get[title]] +[join[/]]
```

This solution was created by Jeremy Ruston as an [answer to my post on the Tiddlywiki google groups forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tiddlywiki/a-EhnBSVUL4/reY8DFB9EwAJ)